# Xcode pulling from repository has missing cocoapod files

Tags: xcode, git, cocoapods

I just learnt how to use cocoapods yesterday and I installed a few libraries from fellow github members. I have a private repository where I save my changes. I'm still not familiar with cocoapods and I'm having an issue where when I check out my repository, the libraries I installed from cocoapods are missing. While `pod install` fixes the issue, I'm still not sure why I cant commit and push certain libraries to my own repository.

Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I question why you want to push libraries to Git in the first place.  I have worked with many frameworks using Git and I have never seen this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Just a habit to make sure I don't accidentally delete my whole project, so I'm not supposed to push those libraries which i installed from cocoapods?

Comment: The thing is, Git generally does a lousy job of versioning binary library files.  And these dependencies could change at some point as you upgrade etc.  I don't know iOS at all, but my guess is that there are one or more configuration files which tells xCode which libraries to build with.  This file is what should be committed to Git and not the libraries themselves.